# How to scrape a single element out of 2 elements having same set of attributes and same hierarchy in html source code (using python's beautiful soup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

[image: This is the source code of IMDB website]

I want to scrap the element highlighted in blue color in the image.That element represents the "no of votes" for a particular movie.When ever I try to scrape it, I am also getting bottom element in the image which represents the "collections" for that movie because both elements have same attributes and in same hierarchy.Is there a way to extract only the highlighted element?

Comment: I am not selecting "no of votes" element for a single movie.I am scraping data of 2000 movies.So I think find_all[0] is not an answer here.

Comment: Then you should give us more information on your data. We can only work with what you throw at us.

Comment: Guys  I appreciate your help! I have to get 2000 'no of votes' elements for 2000 movies.If I use find_all[0] I can only get the 'no of votes' for the first movie,not all.I guess I have to get all 4000 elements('no of votes' and 'collections') and extract only the elements having even index to get the 2000 'no of votes' elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be iterating over all siblings of `<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">` and if you find a `<span name="nv">` thats surrounded by a `<span class="text-muted">` and a `<span class="ghost">` then this must be the span you're looking for. This of course implies that the structure of this snippet of HTML is always the same. If one of those `span`s could be missing then this method obviously fails.

If it's guaranteed that those two spans always are there and in that exact order you could do something like this (your souped HTML is in `html_soup`):

```
votes = html_soup.find("p", {"class": "sort-num_votes-visible").find_all("span", {"name": "nv"})[0]
```

---

**EDIT:**

According to your comment you could do the following in order to parse the votes for multiple movies:

```
for p in html_soup.find("p", {"class": "sort-num_votes-visible"}):
    votes = p.find_all("span", {"name": "nv"})[0]

    < Put whatever code here for each of your movies
      ...
    >
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) Would very much appreciate it when you'd accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this(assuming that you are using BeautifulSoup):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('yourhtml', 'lxml')
p_sort = soup.find('p', {'class':'sort-num_votes-visible'})
req_span = p_sort.find_all('span', {'name':'nv'})[0]
```

`req_span` will contain the tag you were asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If order of these 2 similar span elements are same, then you can select first element of result or use .find() instead of .find_all()[0].

Answer (score 1):

I think `parsel` is a better html parse package with `xpath` support.

```
from parsel import Selector

s = Selector(text=html)
nv_data = s.xpath('//span[@name="nv"]/@data-value').extract_first()
```